# Make a copy of Google Doc after clicking ui.alert

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How do I invoke a make a copy of google doc in my drive when I click a ui.alert ok button in an existing google doc template?

```html
function onOpen() {
  var loadCopy = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/(Doc ID)/copy';
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Notification:', '......', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

  var loadCopy = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/(Doc ID)/copy';

  loadCopy();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors or issues when utilizing that particular code ?

Comment: no, it just pop up the ui.alert with ok button.  After click ok, there is no copy being make

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab a hold of the file through the DriveApp to get a type FILE.  Then you can use the makeCopy() method.  Edited per our comment stream to remove the ui.alert() and Replace it with a ui.modalDialog() so that we can make an HTML Link to the new document for the user to click on.  Apps Scripts cannot open a new tab like HTML can.

```
function onOpen()
{
  thisDocId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()
  //copy the file
  sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisDocId)
  thisFileName = sourceFile.getName()
  var newNameString = thisFileName + "Copied by Script"
  var newFile = sourceFile.makeCopy(newNameString)
  var newFileUrl = newFile.getUrl()
  // Create a Modal HTML Dialog Box
  var stringHTML='<h1><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="'+ newFileUrl + '">'
  stringHTML += "Click Here to open your copy" + "</a></h1>"
  Logger.log(stringHTML)
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(stringHTML)
  html.setWidth(800)
  html.setHeight(300)
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Modal Dialog Title');
}
```

**References**

- [Class DriveApp makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy())
- [Class Ui Alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String))
- [Class Ui Modal Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))

Comment: Not working.  I was trying to invoke this https://docs.google.com/document/d/(Doc ID)/copy#  which works.  How do I trigger the URL directly from Apps Script

Comment: What do you mean by Trigger?  The Solution I posted above makes the document copy as soon as you select the Yes button in the Alert Popup.

Comment: got what meant but I don't want people to go into the original template so I change to just ui.Button.Ok

Comment: But then you want this user who opened your document, and then clicked OK to then be transported to the new tab with the copied document and the original tab with the original doc to be closed?

Comment: Lets switch gears and stop using the ui.Alert and use a Ui.ModalDialog so we can make the html Link to click on.  I'll Update my Answer with New Code

Comment: Thanks AWoods but I received bad request Error 400.  I have added a screenshot of what happened when I click on the download link.

Comment: My guess is that the Error400 is caused by your string of html has an error in it.  Send the String of html to the Logger.log() and read through it looking for mistakes.  Post or share code so we can see.

Comment: Thanks AWoods.  Apologies I was down with Covid.  I will test the code again and reply soonest.